# What is the appropriate command when one is thirsty?

Tags: word-choice

If when I am hungry I can command someone to "feed me", what is the equivalent command when I am thirsty? For years I have joked with friends that it must be "quench me", however, I doubt that this is right.

Comment: The active version of *drink* is *drench*. There's a question or two on that.

Comment: @Mitch  Yes, see Fumble-Fingers' answer which was swamped. :http://english.stackexchange.com/a/36498/44619 However, Janus's answer is clearer and well argued.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, of course, the object of ‘quench’ must be a thirst or desire of some kind—not the person who is thirsty or desirous. But I take it you know that, and that is why you say you’ve *joked* with your friends.

‘Quench’ is not a real equivalent for ‘feed’. The latter simply means to give someone food (whether it fills them up or not), while the former means to *extinguish* a thirst. In other words, ‘quench’ is the liquid counterpart to ‘sate’

I don’t know of a word that specifically corresponds to ‘feed’, but for liquid items; I would guess there isn’t one. But since you can say of babies that they *feed* on breast milk, and breast milk is liquid, I guess you might at a stretch be able to expand ‘feed’ to include liquids, too. I wouldn’t count on others to understand it out of context, though.

On a more historical note, ‘feed’ is in origin simply an i-umlaut causative¹ of ‘food’. If we apply this same strategy to ‘drink’, we arrive at a verb that does exist, but has developed a slightly different meaning over the centuries: *drench*.

So if you are just looking to joke with your mates, you might say, “I am hungry—feed me! I am thirsty—drench me!”

---

¹ In the older stages of the Germanic languages, *i*-umlaut, from the Proto-Germanic suffix *-j(a)*, in its turn from the Proto-Indo-European causative suffix *-ei̯e/o-*, is the most common way of denoting causative verbs meaning ‘make someone do X’.

Comment: I always thought _drench_ was synonymous with _soak_ as in, "He was drenched from head to foot."

Comment: I'm with @Mari-LouA on this - to me, drench would imply externally applied water.

Comment: Yes, that is the slightly different meaning the verb has acquired over the centuries—it's original, literal meaning is ‘cause (someone) to drink’. This is why I caveated it with “if you are just looking to joke with your mates”.

Comment: [DYAC](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com)! That was naturally supposed to say, “its original, literal meaning”. No stray apostrophes here, please!

Answer (score 4):

You could say 'water me!', as if you were a plant.

Comment: Or, "feed and water me!" as if you were a horse.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised this isn't here . . . ***hydrate*** me!

> **From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hydrate):**
>
> ***hydrate*** - transitive verb
>
> 1: to cause to take up or combine with water or the elements of water
>
> 2: to supply with ample fluid or moisture
>
> ***Hydrate*** - intransitive verb
>
> Examples of HYDRATE:
>
> *"lotions and creams that hydrate the skin"*
>
> *"Drink fluids to hydrate the body."*

Comment: Not sure about that. While, "feed me!" indicates providing food of any kind, "feed" also works as "feed me some grapes!" "Hydrate me some wine!" just doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, @Dane, you're right.  It's kinda ok as a stand-alone command but falls apart when you add something like "...some wine".  hmmm.

Comment: But it would work if you used a preposition. *Hydrate me with wine!*

Comment: _Feed me with grapes!_ Actually, on second thought, isn't it pretty much always rude to command someone, "feed me?" It's probably more polite to give the command to an assistant in reference to a third party, such as "Feed them the best steak." In which case, "Give them the best wine" really isn't bad at all.

Answer (score 3):

In the circles I move in, which are not always the most sophisticated, it is not uncommon to hear people say "Beer me!", but always in a jocular tone.

Comment: When reading the question, "Beer me!" immediately came to mind. I've heard, "Beer me some soda," so it is a general term for liquid refreshment. Just wait, in a few years it might be in the dictionary. :-) That said, I think the real answer is already over here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36489/eat-is-to-feed-as-drink-is-to-what

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

If you are the maitre d' commanding a waiter, you say, "**Serve** them the 2007 Merlot."

If you are the medic at a race, you say, "**Hydrate** the runners."

If you are a cowboy you say, "**Water** the horses."

If you are a nursing coach, you say, "**Feed** the baby."

If you are dying of thirst, you say, "**Water, please.**"

If you are joking with buddies, you say, "**Beer** me."

If you are a petulant tyrant, you say, "**Drown** me," and hopefully someone does.

Comment: I've never told a waiter to feed a customer. "Serve them the filet mignon", surely?

Comment: @PhilMJones, I'm happy to remove that example. It just strikes me that saying, "Feed me," is rarely, if ever, good form. Can you think of when else "feed" is used as a command?

Comment: "Feed me, Seymour, feed me now!" (Little Shop of Horrors) is a rather extreme example :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one, which may sound unusual but which I think any native speaker will immediately understand:

"Slake me."

The Free Dictionary gives as the first sense:
        To satisfy (a craving); quench: slaked her thirst.
and as the third sense:
        To cool or refresh by wetting or moistening.

Link: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slake

Comment: If you said "Slake my thirst." rather than "Slake me." I'd agree.